# how to convert particular dataframe columns into list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```html
C_name,Score,rank
raj,488,1
sai,480,2
john,350,3
dev,340,4
mani,270,5
```

this is my dataframe and i have to convert c_name column into list..Is is possible to convert column into list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print df.C_name.tolist()
['raj', 'sai', 'john', 'dev', 'mani']
```